# What is the proper way to marshall utf-8 encoded string to Haskell text and back?

Tags: haskell, encoding, utf-8

I have C string that is guaranteed to be UTF-8 encoded. With simple strings I would do it like this (assuming that we can use `pack` and `unpack`):

```
result <- peekCString cstr
free cstr -- ← not really important here
return (T.pack result)
```

And to use string:

```
withCString (T.unpack str) $ \cstr ->
  use_string cstr
```

Problem with these functions is that

> they will use an encoding determined by the current locale

…but I know that it always should be UTF-8, if current locale specifies different encoding, I'll get wrong results.

So, how should I approach the marshalling to and from `Text`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using `ByteString` as an intermediary type, rather than `String`, as that will allow you to use `Data.Text.Encoding` to manually decode and encode the strings.

```
module Main where

import Data.ByteString
import Data.Text
import Data.Text.Encoding
import Foreign.C.String
import Foreign.Marshal.Alloc

decode :: CString -> IO Text
decode cstr = do
  bytestr <- packCString cstr
  return (decodeUtf8 bytestr)

encode :: Text -> (CString -> IO a) -> IO a
encode text cont =
  useAsCString (encodeUtf8 text) cont
```

Woo, import party.